# An element of $\ell^2$ wanted

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

I am looking for an element $x=(x_0,x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ in $\ell^2$ such that the sequence $z_n, n=0,1,2,\cdots$ defined by 
$$z_n=2^n(x_n, x_{n+1},\cdots)$$  is dense in $\ell^2$.
It seems that this is hard to do, but such $x$ exists by an indirect method (using Birkhorff transitivity theorem), see Dynamics of Linear Operators by Bayart and Matheron, p. 6.

Comment: The gliding hump.  A method used in Banach sequence spaces a lot.

Comment: What about ordering the countable dense set of rational and eventually null sequences properly weighted into a sequence?

Comment: [Here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm32/sm3213.pdf) is the article of S. Rolewicz where this was first proved. An elementary and constructive proof is contained therein.